# Update object key values in array of objects that is JSONB in PSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, object, jsonb

Link to example that only changes first occurance: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wd6jJmDxGp3W1x6ptrEjB4/0

Example Data:

| id (int) | application_questions (JSONB) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id":1,"type":"single-select"},{"id":2,"type":"multi-select-check"}, {"id":3,"type":"single-select"},{"id":4,"type":"multi-select-check"}, {"id":5,"type":"single-select"},{"id":6,"type":"multi-select-check"}] |
| 2 | [{"id":1,"type":"single-select"},{"id":2,"type":"multi-select-check"}, {"id":3,"type":"single-select"},{"id":4,"type":"multi-select-check"}] |
| 3 | [{"id":1,"type":"single-select"},{"id":2,"type":"multi-select-check"}, {"id":3,"type":"single-select"},{"id":4,"type":"multi-select-check"}] |

I have a JSONB column where each record is an array of objects. Each object has the key `type`.

What I want to do is update each `type` if it matches a condition. For example if `type` is `multi-select-check` then change it to `multi-select-combo`, but leave the types that are not `multi-select-check` unchanged.

What I have found is that it is possible to change the first occurrence of type C but the others in that same list are ignored (see my db-fiddle example).

Please enlighten me.

Comment: I arrived at a working solution: ```update requisitions
set application_questions = replace(application_questions::text, '"type": "multi-select-check"', '"type": "multi-select-combo"')::json;```